# System hangs after resuming from suspend

Tags: suspend, restart

Recently I am encountering this problem. The system hangs after resuming from suspend. The system works again only after force restart. has any one encountered this before. Pls point out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ya i too had the problem with my Dell laptop... I called the Dell service engg and he told that is a graphical device problem and need to change the graphics card... But since that is a laptop I have changed my entire motherboard and after that It works fine... Finally that is a graphics hardware problem...

Comment: i am using a Toshiba satellite and dont have graphics card other than the inbuilt one. Also i encounter this problem infrequently. Any way thank you for the suggestion. If the problem persists I will check with Toshiba Service. in the mean time lets wait for response from others.